# Foursquare API Lists -> ListItems -> ?Venues?

Tags: api, foursquare

Via the foursquare API and documentation, i'm trying to extract venues from lists.

I'm hitting getting a list response, which has listItems, which is suppose to be "count and items of list items on this list."

What the API responds with is just the count.

```
    {
      id: "510ae78ae4b0607cd8d8504f"
      name: "Brunchn'"
      description: ""
      user: {
        id: "157255"
        firstName: "Jon"
        lastName: "Doe"
        gender: "male"
        relationship: "self"
        photo: {
          prefix: "https://irs3.4sqi.net/img/user/"
          suffix: "/POOIJDBXTTRPSB0.jpg"
        }
      }
      editable: true
      public: true
      collaborative: false
      url: "https://foursquare.com/jon_doe/list/brunch"
      canonicalUrl: "https://foursquare.com/jon_doe/list/brunch"
      createdAt: 1359669130
      updatedAt: 1364583099
      followers: {
        count: 0
      }
      listItems: {
        count: 3
      }
    }
```

from the documentation, if i get the item response, I can retrieve the venue, but there doesn't seem to be a connection, or i'm going at this from the wrong API call.  Anyone have any suggestions?

The call is https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/lists

Comment: What's the listId you're trying to get info about?

Comment: I'm trying to get the venues from lists i've created.